# Async call based on a response from a previous call, avoiding callback hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

So I usually deal with async functions by using the `.then` chain. But this time it doesn't solve it. This is the situation.

```
return Promise.all([
    Banner.findOne(),
    event.findOne({
        status: true
    }),
    Account.find({
        accType: 'employer'
    })
        .then(([banner, event, account]) => {
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Web Project Studio',
                user: req.user,
                banner: banner,
                event: event,
                employer: account
            });
        }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    })
]);
```

So this worked, and all was great. But now I decided to change the way to select the active `event`. I'm calling a collection called `generalInfo` and grabbing the ID to the current event from there. Here's what I have so far:

```
return Promise.all([
    Banner.findOne(),
    GeneralInfo.findOne(),
    Account.find({
        accType: 'employer'
    })
]).then(([banner, generalInfo, account]) => {
        Event.findById(generalInfo.activeEventId).then(r => {
            console.log('test');
            var event = r;
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Web Project Studio',
                user: req.user,
                banner: banner,
                event: event,
                employer: account
            });
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
})
```

But this code starts to look like a callback hell.

I also tried something like this:

```
var banner = await Banner.findOne().catch(e => console.log(e));
var currentEvent = await GeneralInfo.findOne().catch(e => console.log(e));
currentEvent.then(async r => {
    var event = await Event.findOneById(r.activeEventId).catch(e => console.log(e));
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

It's not completed but it kind of shows my way of thinking. But again, no luck.

So how can I get along with async without chaining `.then` forever? I need to pass all the returned objects to the `render` function.

Comment: Before I post an answer, I'm curious if you'd be willing to create an observable from your promise (or promises). 

If so, you could merge with map, concat, and all those great observable operators that let you do this kind of thing in a procedural-like (but of course async) way. If you're not interested in rxjs though I'll leave it be.

Comment: I have no idea what that is but I'm all for any answers

Comment: Ah: you really (really!) need to look up "rxjs" and explore "observables". Basically, they let you represent data as a "stream" that you can merge with other streams, make wait until other streams are ready, and all that. Promises are good for what they're good for (pretty much, instant one-shot executions) but start to fall apart stylistically when you need to manage multiple async streams, especially if they need to be managed in sequence, joined, retried, and so on. 

It takes some effort, but these days, you really need rxjs under your belt if you're doing async work.

Comment: Anyway, an Observable (thing that represents an async stream of data) can wrap a promise so that you can use the Observable operators and so on. Definitely look up "multiple streams in rxjs" and you'll get all kinds of tutorials and code samples on how to go about it.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!

Comment: Note: there's an extra `}` (and some odd indentation) in the "Here's what I have so far:" code above. The versions in my answer correct that (in addition to their main purpose: answering the question :-) ). FWIW, your edit to my answer changed the chaining so it didn't match your first code block in the question, so I reverted the answer edit.

Comment: Oh. Yes, I messed it up. Sorry about that! Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just nest earlier, which has the advantage of overlapping more as well (see `***` comment(s)):

```
return Promise.all([
    Banner.findOne(),
    GeneralInfo.findOne()
        .then(generalInfo => Event.findById(generalInfo.activeEventId)), // ***
    Account.find({
        accType: 'employer'
    })
}).then(([banner, event, account]) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Web Project Studio',
        user: req.user,
        banner: banner,
        event: event,
        employer: account
    });
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

If you do that generalInfo => event thing a lot, you might wrap it in a utility function.

Alternately, if they shouldn't overlap like that, you can minimize the nesting by adding another `then`:

```
return Promise.all([
    Banner.findOne(),
    GeneralInfo.findOne(),
    Account.find({
        accType: 'employer'
    })
]).then(([banner, generalInfo, account]) => {
    return Event.findById(generalInfo.activeEventId).then(event => { // ***
        return [banner, event, account];                             // ***
    });                                                              // ***
}).then(([banner, event, account]) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Web Project Studio',
        user: req.user,
        banner: banner,
        event: event,
        employer: account
    });
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
return Promise.all([
  Banner.findOne(),
  GeneralInfo.findOne(),
  Account.find({
    accType: 'employer'
  })
]).then(async ([banner, generalInfo, account]) => {
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Web Project Studio',
      user: req.user,
      banner: banner,
      event: await Event.findById(generalInfo.activeEventId),
      employer: account
    });
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
})
```